# Vb.Net - Count number of columns returned by Data Reader

Tags: vb.net

I have this code, which returns data from datareader. But query may be dynamic, and it might send 3 or 4 or even 5 columns. How can I capture this, because i want to generate a HTML table from the rows/columns returned

```
Dim _ExecutionResultsReader As SqlDataReader
_ExecutionResultsReader = _DMTSQLCommand.ExecuteReader()
While _ExecutionResultsReader.Read()
emailBody = emailBody + _ExecutionResultsReader(0).ToString()
emailBody = emailBody + "<br>"
End While
```

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [FieldCount](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.fieldcount%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) properrty to obtain that info.

If necessary you can also [retreive the column schema](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310108/en-us).

Comment: Thanks, can you advice how to get COLUMN NAME from data reader also.

Comment: Just edited my question with your comment question. Must have read your mind ;-)